# Name of the author vanishes on titlepage

Tags: titles, document-classes

I cannot figure out why everything but the author's name appear on my title page. I use `\documentclass[12pt]{uvamath}` from my university and

```
\title{Title}
\what{Blabla paper}
\author{Person}
\supervisors{Person1}
\secondgrader{Person2}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}
\maketitle
```

and the title page misses the author although the little block on the second page with all the data turns out fine.

My only lines before that looks like:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{uvamath}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}

\usepackage{amsmath,amscd}
\usepackage{amssymb}  
\usepackage{amsthm}  
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,calc}
%\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{lpic}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathpzc}{OT1}{pzc}{m}{it}
```

Comment: If you are using the correct class and the title page does not show author's name, maybe this is the desired result. Did you checked with other works produced with this class?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but I checked and there is an author's name usually. So that's not the problem..

Comment: @Judith: Are you using [this template on Github](https://github.com/jzuiddam/uvamath)? I compile your code snippet in a minimal example and it displays the `\author` and `\supervisors`, but not the `\secondgrader`.

Comment: Yes exactly! Except that I use some different packages and English. I don't want the secondgrader on the title page, but I cannot miss the author. I use the same order and commands as in the template, but the author doesn't show..

Comment: I installed the package lipsum now, so the only difference is that I have more packages as far as I can see. I added my first lines in the question. I don't see what goes wrong here?

Comment: @JudithBerendsen: I can't replicate your problem. :-|

Answer (score 1):

I compiled this, downloaded from [enter link description here](http://jzuiddam.github.io/week3/uvamath/)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{uvamath}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}

\usepackage{amsmath,amscd}
\usepackage{amssymb}  
\usepackage{amsthm}  
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,calc}
%\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{lpic}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathpzc}{OT1}{pzc}{m}{it}


\title{Title}
\what{Blabla paper}
\author{Person}
\supervisors{Person1}
\secondgrader{Person2}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

and it produces

[image]

Looks ok to me.

Comment: I agree, but unfortunately there is still no author in my document :( But I have two reported errors now, both in line 1: Usage of deprecated font command `\bf'!(scrreprt) You should note, that in 1994 font command `\bf' has(scrreprt) been defined for compatiblitiy to Script 2.0 only. and No \author given. (although it's there!)

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example, is a complete yet short latex file that demonstrates the problem you have.  Does the file I produced generate the same problem?  If yes, then perhaps latex is finding an old version of uvamath.cls.  If no, then there is likely a problem with your latex file, which we cannot see.

Comment: I made a new file and ran the title page just as you did, still no title. If it's an outdated version, where can I find the newest one? It shows no error..

Comment: There is a link at the top of my answer.  One thing that can happen is that you have multiple versions of the same file on your system.  Try first to download the zip file on the website above, unzip it, and stick the contents in the folder that contains your latex file.

Comment: Thank you! now it works perfectly. Also the newer version solved my problems with the hyperlinks :)